# Grammar for ask

Tags: modal-verbs, passive-voice, sentence-structure, future-tense

I know this sounds right:

> If I were to ask you how to [verb][object], you'd say...

but I want to word it this way instead:

> If the question of how to [verb][object] **was asked** of you, you'd say...

Is that second version above incorrect?
Or are only one of the following correct?

> If the question of how to [verb][object] **were asked** of you, you'd say...

OR

> If the question of how to [verb][object] **were to be asked** of you, you'd say..."
>   *(makes my line length longer than wanted)*

Comment: It's enough to say *if the question of how to **verb + object** was asked, you'd say ...*

Comment: Great! Can I keep "was asked of you, you'd say..."

Comment: You're gonna have to wait for a native response, but I think it's actually *... from you.*

Comment: Ok, thank you. Let's see what others think as well. It is a tricky one.

Answer (score 3):

There are two separate issues.

First, the passive form: *Ask*, as a ditransitive verb, potentially has two passive forms.

> You are asked the question
>
> The question is asked of you.

Both are grammatical, but the first is much more common in speech: the second is rather literary. They both have the same meaning.

Second, the conditional. For *irrealis* (or counter-factual) conditionals, the traditional grammar is to use the so-called "past subjunctive" form; but in modern English, only one verb retains a distinct form for this: *were* as opposed to *was*. For every other verb, it is indistinguishable from the simple past.

So for example

> If I did see him ...

is historically a different form from the simple past.

But in the case of *was*, the traditional form

> If I were ...

is used for conterfactuals (as opposed to the simple past for non-counterfactuals, such as *If I was there at the time, I didn't see anything*, where the speaker may have been there at the time).

Having said all that, many speakers today never use the *were* form, and say *if I was* in all senses. But traditionalists still count that as "wrong".

So *If the question were asked of you ...* is perfectly grammatical, but a bit literary, and most people would say *If you were asked the question ...*.

(I don't think many people would say *If the question was asked of you ...*, because the literary form *was asked of you* doesn't sit well with the colloquial *if ... was*; but some people might say it).

Comment: +1. With regard to *literary* contexts: in American English, "ask of" is used not with questions but with extraordinary deeds, with "calls to action". The range of the *extraordinary* extends from small favors all the way to acts of heroism.  *I have a favor to ask of you ... If such acts of self-sacrifice were asked of you, how would you respond?* At the heroic end of the spectrum, **ask of** has a strident literary quality but at the shallow end of the pool, the effect is modest: it announces "I need your help" but it could be only with feeding the dog for two days while I'm out of town.

Comment: Fair point, @TRomano; except that if I search for "asked of" in the Corpus of Global Web-based English, and look at a random couple of pages of the US English results, about half of the citations are about questions, and the other half about duties. The proportion (of questions) does seem to be a little higher in UK English.

Comment: Are you saying "If the question **was** asked..." is incorrect?

Comment: Thank you for all the information. I should have said this is for a book I am writing and is meant to have a literary tone. I am a native English speaker from the Midwest but now live out West.

Comment: Based on Colin's statement, maybe I should change it to: "if the question of how to treat cats were asked of you" vs. "was asked"?

Comment: It would be great if I could contact Colin Fine somehow because I have a British English version of my book and an American English version. My e-mail is tied to my account if it can be seen by administrators.

Comment: @WriteroutWest: I think the choice of "was" or "were" will say something about the character speaking. Is your cat an alley cat or a toff?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to contact people privately via StackExchange, and I'm not about to post my email here. But if you go searching for my name, I think you'll find ways of contacting me.

Comment: Thank you, Colin. He is a well-mannered and well-read cat so "were" sounds like it would be best!!!

Comment: Can't you use "would have been"? If a question would have been asked of you..

Comment: @SovereignSun: the use of "would" inside an "if" clause is something which I've seen increasingly often in recent years. I would never use it myself, and in the past it would certainly have been counted "incorrect". To me it also sounds distinctly American.